# How to change folder icon

Tags: customization, directory

I would like to change a

> **folder icon** to a **.ico** file

How to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, it can`t be done, because the ICO file format is an image file format for computer icons in Microsoft Windows.